# Apostrophes in links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Alright, wikipedia allows apostrophes in their links and when I tried to add one of said links to a comment, the url gets cut off at the apostrophe. This also occurs in Questions (I would assume answers as well), you can see and example of it in this post.

see: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/suggestions-for-a-real-time-strategic-space-fleet-game 2nd comment by "Revoked" (me) I was linking to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game

I know from experience apostrophes are fairly uncommon in links, but being that this is from wikipedia might make it worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help

**In this case you want to use the `[link](http://example.com)` style**

```
all the ways to link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game  
<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game>  
[Ender's Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game)  
[Ender's Game][1]  
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game">Ender's Game</a>  

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game
```

all the ways to link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game

[Ender's Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game)
[Ender's Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game)
[Ender's Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game)

Answer (score 1):

Encode your apostrophe as %27, then it should work.

For the record, the team has also turned down support for parentheses (which is fairly common in MSDN articles on SO), so the fact that Wikipedia has apostrophes isn't significant enough to warrant more consideration.

Comment: Or use old HTML A tags.

Comment: Well yeah sure of course encoding works. But this is my point: if you consider the tools given to the user, who (other than webdevs) is going to know they need to go find the encoded character for an apostrophe or a parentheses? Maybe this is a dead horse but, I understand not wanting to support the output, but how about you *support the input*??

Comment: They should be making the links with actual text rather than just copying the link itself. The WYSIWYG editor supports it just fine.

Comment: The editor doesn't let you include links with text when making comments though for some reason. At least in my previous attempts, it's not worked. :/

Comment: [The text links allowed in comments are inline links with the brackets -> parenthesis notation](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364/apostrophes-in-links/365#365 "It even supports tooltips!") @Fallen

Comment: @Grace - Thanks for the tip! I'm a new user to the SO sites overall, so I'm still unsure of the syntax for some stuff.

Comment: @Juan Duly noted, shall look into when I head home tonight.